# Why on earth would rsync over SMB run nearly five times faster than rsync-to-rsync (over SSH)?

Tags: ssh, samba, rsync

I just modified many files on a 36TB Unraid array (not quite half full yet). Now I want to sync all of those changes up to a backup array using rsync.

My usual rsync backup was going a lot more slowly than I expected, running at only around 25MB/sec when I can normally expect 100MB/sec or more on my wired gigabit network. After a few experiments I found a way to get the speed I expected, but the solution makes no sense.

My original rsync backup command looked like this:

`rsync -rltOuv --delete --force /mnt/user/video/ root@192.168.42.12:/mnt/user/video/`

I updated to using this, accessing the backup server via an SMB share, and got a roughly 500% increase in speed:

`rsync -rltOuv --delete --force /mnt/user/video/ /mnt/remotes/TRANTOR_video/`

I'd prefer to use rsync over SSH and better preserve Linux file permissions and ownership, but not at the expense of a terribly slower backup.

Any ideas why the SSH version of this backup is so much slower at communicating with the same backup array via SMB?

Comment: The bottleneck could be the CPU time required for the encryption with SSH.

Comment: @Esa, that's a thought. I'll have to try some transfers (after a current big backup is done) with SSH again and check the CPU usage on both ends. I didn't pick an very high-powered CPU for my Unraid systems, but I'd hope even a recent model Core i3 wouldn't be too taxed by SSH encryption.

Comment: You're not going to get a 500% increase in speed if you're already getting 25MB/s on a gigabit network. The theoretical maximum would be 100MB/s. Perhaps you meant 25Mb/s? Having the correct units is really important when considering network speeds

Comment: "_I'd prefer to use rsync over SSH and better preserve Linux file permissions and ownership_" - neither of your `rsync` commands is set up to do that

Comment: For clarification, you're pushing the backup from the server running Unraid? What kind of server is it (OS) and how much CPU power and RAM does it have? Same two questions for the other device too, please.

Comment: @Chris Davies, sorry, I just forgot to put the p and o options back for this post. I'm pushing from my main Unraid server to a backup Unraid server. Both are the same, not super powerful, 4-core  i3-10100 CPU @ 3.60GHz with 8GB RAM. Still, I didn't imagine SSH encryption would be that challenging.

Comment: If you don't provide the commands you're actually complaining about, we're unlikely to be able to help